# 'object' does not contain a definition Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am hoping someone can assist as i am new to xamarin development.
I can confirm that if i hardcode a variable into *ProductID* the code works correctly.

The full error i am getting is;
*"Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Product_ID' and no accessible extension method 'Product_ID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*

The method that i am reciving this error in is;

```
    private async void ListStockTakeServices_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ProductID = e.Item?.Product_ID;
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ListViewPage(ProductID));
    }
```

Below is an image to (as far as i can see) prove that there is infact a "Product_ID" variable

[Visual Studio Locals Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCq87.png)

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is basic C#.  You need to cast `object` to the correct type in order to access its properties

```
int ProductID = ((Overviews)e.Item).Product_ID;
```

Comment: This fixed my issue, Thank you very much

Comment: Bad question, great answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for the 'why' this casting is required. 
We can observe a difference between what's there at compile time and what's there at runtime.

*Warning: 

the word 'object' is used below to denote either the `object` type or as a synonym to 'instance', 'value', 'the thingy'*

At compile time, the compiler looks at the types of objects, and that's what it works with. It cannot deduce that it will be an `Overviews` object when program runs. All it knows is that `e.Item` is of type `object`. It's kind of a declaration saying: "this will be just an `object`". As `object` doesn't have a `Product_ID` property, the compilator protests by saying: *'object' does not contain a definition for 'Product_ID'*

You can see the declared type of `e.Items` by hovering over `e.Items` or in the documentation for [ItemTappedEventArgs.Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.itemtappedeventargs.item?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ItemTappedEventArgs_Item).

What you've seen during runtime is the **actual** parameter (as opposed to a **formal** parameter in the method's declaration), in this case an `Overviews` object. When you write your program, you know that it's an `Overviews` object where the compiler doesn't. As we have more knowledge about what is happening in the program, we sometimes "fix" compiler's assumptions. In this case, we're telling the compiler that `e.Item` is not just an `object` object but an `Overviews` object.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this further